# ubuntu, nginx: php5-fpm is segfaulting

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I'm setting up a freshly new root server.
so the installation worked fine so far but when i want try to access to my page, i get a 502 bad gateway. first initialization of nginx worked and i got the nginx welcome page, i just configured in nginx/sites-available/default that root is in var/www and added index.php to index.

in dmesg:

```
[18710.693648] php5-fpm[14673]: segfault at 2c ip 00000000006e00ba sp 00007ffc23f14660 error 4 in php5-fpm[400000+7a5000]
[18712.179472] traps: php5-fpm[14674] general protection ip:6e00c1 sp:7ffc23f14660 error:0 in php5-fpm[400000+7a5000]
```

I tried to change it to use a network socket instead of a unix socket and it didn't make any difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is the site you are looking for: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Segfault usually comes up when there is something wrong and you're using all your memory allocated. Its definitely something with your nginx configuration. Can you put your nginx .conf configuration here?

Comment: This definitely has nothing to do with nginx. Check your PHP installation and your script. Check if simplest script like `<?php phpinfo() ?>` works.

Comment: ok, yes phpinfo works, so it's not an nginx missconfiguration?
i just installed a fresh copy of asgardCMS